# How to read values from a file into textbox and write back from textbox to the same file in NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I have to read values from a ini file and put them into some text boxes once user is done with the change he/she can write back these changes to that file.
like

```
[userdetail]
username = "abc"
[personaldetail]
address = äbc.."
work profession = "banker"
```

NSIS file:

```
;define textbox  
${NSD_CreateText} 78.33u 5.23u 200.67u 12.31u $Text_State  
Pop $Text


;read value  :
ReadINIStr $Text_State  "C:\ProgramData\testing\test\pnd.ini" "user" "userdetail"
push $Text_State
pop $Text_State

WriteINIStr "$APPDATA\testing\test\pnd.ini" "user" "userdetail" "$Text_State"
```

Why am I always getting a blank text box value?

Comment: Fixed formatting. Improved grammar

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using **C:\ProgramData** folder in ReadINIStr and **$APPDATA** folder in WriteINIStr ?

$APPDATA is expanded (based on SetShellVar) to C:\Users[User]\AppData\Roaming.

So basically you are reading ad writing to different files.

Comment: I suppose that it is answer as he is reading and writing to different files.

Comment: Hey Slappy i just investigate the things and what i find is C:\ProgramData and $APPDATA are the same thing in my case. I am able to read and fill the textboxes but i am not able to write values back to the file from the textboxes. Can you share some examples for the same.